# std::move is calling copy constructor instead of move constructor when initiallizing in the same line?

Tags: c++11

below is class Foo for which i  have created a copy constructor, copy assignment operator and a move constructor.

```
class Foo
{
public:
Foo() = default;

Foo(Foo const& other)   //copy ctor
{
    if (other.i != nullptr)
        i = new int(*other.i);
}

Foo& operator=(Foo const& other)  //assignment operator
{
    if (other.i != nullptr)
        i = new int(*other.i);
    return *this;
}

Foo& operator=(Foo&& other)  //move ctor. I'm not sure whether this can                           //be used as a move ctor
{
    if (other.i != nullptr)
    {
        i = other.i;
        other.i = nullptr;
    }

    return *this;
}

~Foo()
{
    if (i != nullptr)
    {
        delete i;
        i = nullptr;
    }
}

int *i = nullptr;
};
```

when i write below code,

```
Foo f2;
f2.i = new int(43);
Foo f1 = std::move(f2);
```

it calls the copy constructor instead of move constructor.
But when i write it like below,

```
Foo f2;
f2.i = new int(43);
Foo f1;
f1 = std::move(f2);
```

it calls the move constructor i defined. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: I don't see a move constructor.

Comment: What you've labeled `move ctor` *is not* a constructor--it's an assignment operator (specifically move assignment).

Answer (score 1):

You provided move *assignment*, but not a move *constructor*.  When I added one (below), I move operations are used as expected.

```
Foo(Foo && other) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "Move ctor\n";
    i = other.i;
    other.i = nullptr;
}
```

Note the use of `noexcept`; you can also add that to your move assignment operator.